# How do I best resolve this MATLAB name conflict?

Tags: matlab, path

I have saved some data in MATLAB data files, where the variable name of each of the files is `times`. When I now try to read those data files, it seems to create a name conflict with (I think) the built-in function `times`.

The lines:

```
load("matlabcode\eeglab2020_0//timesBxintIlow.mat","times"); 
times1=times;
```

lead to the error:

```
Error using  .* 
Not enough input arguments.
```

The error actually doesn't appear when I type it into the MATLAB console, but only when I call the function that uses the 2 lines from the console)

Can I change the name of my variable "times" somehow?

I have tried locating the built-in function:

```
which times
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019b\toolbox\matlab\ops\@char\times)  % char method
```

I don't know what the `@char` means, but `times` seems to be in the folder `ops`. However, changing the name of this file `times` doesn't change the error message. The plan was to programmatically change the name to `times_renamed`, then load the data and then change the name back.

I also could not figure out how to remove the built-in function from the search path.

Comment: Renaming or deleting the file for the `times` function would be useless, as `times.m` doesn't actually do anything (type `edit times` into your command window to read the file), and is a terrible idea anyway in case you want to multiply any numbers or arrays (very likely if you're dealing with data). Can you not edit the data file by hand and rename it, or rename the variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Load](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html) your data into a structure array as follows:

```
S = load("matlabcode\eeglab2020_0//timesBxintIlow.mat", "times");
```

Now you'll be having your required data in `S.times` instead of `times` variable.